# Как получить значение выбранное в select?

Tags: javascript

Для задачи использую библиотеку Tom Select с помощью которой я подгружаю иконки. Сам селект работает отлично. Но мне нужно записать выбранное значение `${data.img}` в отдельную переменную, что бы потом можно было еще подгрузить в другой блок.

Делаю вот так `console.log(a.items[0]);` и вроде получаю ссылку на нужное значение, но при выборе другого значения из селекта оно не меняется.

Кто работал с Tom Select мб в курсе что делать?

```
var a = new TomSelect('#select-beast-empty',{
        valueField: 'img',
        searchField: 'title',
        options: [
            @foreach($allIconsInsideFolder as $icon)
                {id: {{$icon->getInode()}}, title: '{{substr($icon->getFilename(), 0, strrpos($icon->getFilename(),'.'))}}', img: '{{'http://links/public/images/social/'.$icon->getFilename()}}'},
            @endforeach
        ],
        render: {
            option: function(data, escape) {
                return  `
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        <div><img style="background-color: #DCDCDC" width="90" src="${data.img}"></div>
                    </div>
                `;
            },
            item: function(data, escape) {
                return  '<img style="margin-right: 16px; background-color: #DCDCDC" width="30" src="' + escape(data.img) + '">' + '<span class="title">' + escape(data.title) + '</span>';
            }
        }
    });
```